# Configurar user.name

Tags: git

Quando escrevo o comando `git config --global user.name` ocorre o erro:

> could not lock config file z://.gitconfig No such a file or Directory.

A instalação foi feita por default no `C:` mas quando listo o diretorio (`ls`) ele lista o disco `Z:` que está na minha rede.

Comment: Se você está numa rede corporativa, a pasta `home` do usuário pode estar configurada numa unidade mapeada na rede. *(I hate corporate networks)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou assumindo que o sistema operacional é Windows.

## Onde o git procura o arquivo

O arquivo `.gitconfig` com a opção `--global` fica no diretório do usuário do sistema.  [Veja a documentação sobre a configuração.](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

Enquanto no linux o caminho pode ser representado por `~/.gitconfig`, no Windows temos:

- Até o **XP**: `C:\Documents and Settings\<usuario>\.gitconfig`
- Após o **Vista**: `C:\Users\<usuario>\.gitconfig`

Ou, usando a variável de sistema, simplesmente: `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`

## Solução

Verifique o valor da variável de sistema. Corrija esse caminho e dê a permissão necessário para o processo do Git.

## Alternativa

A pergunta cita o comando `ls`, que não é do Windows.

Se estiver usando uma ferramenta como [MSys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), é possível colocar o arquivo de configuração do Git em outro local, como [descrito na documentação](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup).

Basta usar a opção `--system` ao invés de `--global`. O arquivo será armazenado no diretório `/etc/gitconfig`.

Em último caso, a configuração terá que ser feita por repositório.